# MongoDB Aggregation - $sum nested groups

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my Mongo event data in the events collection:

```
[
    { country: "USA", Region: "CA", City: "Los Angeles" },
    { country: "USA", Region: "NY", City: "New York" },
    { country: "USA", Region: "NY", City: "White Plains" },
    { country: "France", Region: "Ile-de-France", City: "Paris" },
    { country: "France", Region: "Bretagne", City: "Brest" },
    { country: "Germany", Region: "", City: "Berlin" }
]
```

If possible I would like to show the event summed by `country` and `region`. The desired output format would be:

```
[
  { 
    country: "USA", 
    count: 3, 
    children: [
      { Region: "NY", count: 2 }, 
      { Region: "CA", count: 1 }
    ]
  },
  { 
    country: "France", 
    count: 2, 
    children: [
      { Region: "Ile-de-France", count: 1 }, 
      { Region: "Bretagne", count: 1 }
    ]
  },
  { 
    country: "Germany", 
    count: 1, 
    children: [ // Region undefined ]
  }
]
```

Here is what I tried:

```
events.aggregate([
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$country', count: {$sum: 1}
  }
}, 
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$_id.country',
    children: {
      $push: {
        Region: '$_id.Region',
        count: {$sum: 1}
      }
    }
  }
}
]
```

The first stage groups and counts the country works on its own. The issue is summing the `Region` parameter. I even removed the `$sum` function from the first stage. All I am getting is:

```
[
  { 
    _id: null, 
    children : [
      { count: 1 }, 
      { count: 1 }, 
      { count: 1 },
      { count: 1 },
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `country` and `Region`.
2. `$group` - Group by `country`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        country: "$country",
        Region: "$Region"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.country",
      children: {
        $push: {
          Region: "$_id.Region",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VWLs6mrm0bf)